# Swift - Extra argument 'image' in call

Tags: ios, swift, arguments

I am trying to turn the following which works

```
tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title))
```

into

```
tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title, image: $0.image))
```

However when I type it I get the following error `Extra argument 'image' in call` now the JSON file does have image so I know its not the JSON return that is causing this error. So It must be something else either in

```
struct NewsData: Decodable{
    let news: [articalData]
}

struct articalData: Decodable{
    let title: String
    let image: String
}
```

or

```
import Foundation
//import UIKit

class News {
  //  var image: UIImage
    var title: String
    var image: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

**Here is the full view controller script**

```
    //
//  NewsViewController.swift
//  DRN1
//
//  Created by Russell Harrower on 26/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Russell Harrower. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation


struct NewsData: Decodable{
    let news: [articalData]
}

struct articalData: Decodable{
    let title: String
    let image: String
}

class NewsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var news: [News] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "News"

         self.newsfetch { [weak self] news in
                    guard let news = news else { return }
                    self?.news = news
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            }
     }


    func newsfetch(_ completionHandler:  @escaping ([News]?)->Void){
        let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/api-access/news"
        guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {  return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl){ (data,response,err)
            in
            guard let news = data else { return }
            do {
                let newsdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsData.self, from: news)
                var tempNews: [News] = []
                newsdata.news.forEach(){
                    var strUrl = $0.image
                    strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

                    tempNews.append(News(title: $0.title, image: strUrl))
                }
                completionHandler(tempNews)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("error json ", jsonErr)
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }.resume()

    }
}


extension NewsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let newsa = news[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as! NewsCell
        cell.setNews(news: newsa)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "shownewsarticle", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as?  NewsArticleViewController{
            destination.article = news[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
            tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: true)
        }

    }


}
```

My first plan is to just get it to not throw that error, and once I have that working i'll use kingfisher to load the remote image.

Comment: I try to compile your code and it works successfully :   tempNews.append(articalData(title: $0.title, image: $0.image)) where tempNews is var tempNews: [articalData] = [] and function signature is func newsfetch(_ completionHandler:  @escaping ([articalData]?)->Void){

Answer (score 2):

```
class News {
  //  var image: UIImage
    var title: String
    var image: String
    init(title: String){
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

The init method does not contain image. This is your issue

**Change to**

```
init(title: String,
     image: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.title = title
}
```